# Evaluate $\iint_{0<x<y<1}xy\,dxdy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}xy &\text{ if } 0<x<y<1, \\ 0 &\text { otherwise. }\end{cases}$$  Evaluate the  integral $\displaystyle \iint f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$.

I'm having trouble with the limits on integration.

Answer (score 3):

Draw the figure..[image]

You will get , $$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^x f(x,y)\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: The integral should run over $y>x$.

Comment: How do you that's the graph? I mean, the given $xy$ is a 3d graph, so why do we graph $x=y$ and $x=1$? Also, there's an answer below by @gt6989b saying that the integral w.r.t x is from $0$ to $y$, while for you it's from $0$ to $x$. Who's right?

Comment: @HeyJude The graph is NOT for the function $f(x,y)$, it is for the region $0<x<y<1$. The answer given by gt6989b and my answer, both the answers are correct. You can evaluate my integration with limits, you will get the same answer as $\frac 18$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

your inequality $0<x<y<1$ indicates you can integrate $\int_0^y fdx$ first. What are the correct limits on the outer $dy$ integral then.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\int f(x,y)\,dx\,dy = \int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^y xy\ dx\ dy=\int_{y=0}^1 \frac{y^3}{2}\ dy = \frac{1}{8}$$

Comment: this is wrong in every posisble way

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate your statement.